# Does the Android application for Teams use an in-app browser?

Tags: microsoft-teams, android-browser

I have an application for Teams that works fine when I use browsers: Chrome, Firefox... and with the Desktop application for Teams.

On the other hand If I try to use this application in my mobile with the Android application for Teams, in this case is not working.

In this application I'm using a indexedDB and I think that this is the problem. I would like to know whether the Android application for Teams is using an in-app browser or another type of in-app browser for Android.

During my researchers I have found this about indexedDB and the Android browsers

[image]

How can I check the version of my Android Browser?

Could you help me with this problem?

Regards

Comment: If that's the case, that it's using the in-built browser, can't you just check the version number within the inbuilt browser on the device (like find the default "browser" app in the app tray)

Comment: HI @HiltonGiesenow, this in-built browser is for Teams (Particular case) or Android (General case)?

Comment: Well, possibly both. Teams won't use it's own "in-built" browser - it will almost certainly be using the native browser on the device ("general case")